# oracle sequence NEXTVAL behavior in case of query execution failure

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence, sql-execution-plan

If Oracle fails to execute the below query due to whatever reason, will the *supplier_seq* get incremented? When exactly does Oracle increment sequences?

```
INSERT INTO suppliers
(supplier_id, supplier_name)
VALUES
(supplier_seq.NEXTVAL, 'Kraft Foods');
```

Comment: Yes, For very sure the `supplier_seq get incremented`. Sequences in oracle get increment by the engine itself irrespective of the query execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence is incremented as soon as `nextval` is called. This increment will never be rolled back. The value is "gone". The only situation where this value could ever be generated again by the sequence, is if the sequence is set to `CYCLE` and it wraps around.

> *due to whatever reason*

The reason *does* matter.

If the statement fails because there is a syntax error or there is no table named `suppliers`, or if the user does not have the privilege to insert into `suppliers` then the sequence will not be incremented (because nextval is never actually called because execution is aborted in an earlier step).

Answer (score 2):

Independently from whether query fails or not, Oracle Sequences are synchronously incremented in all sessions, right when they are called.

However, if there is a syntax error in your statement (wrong tablename, column name etc.), sequence will stay the same since the query won't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you called `supplier_seq.NEXTVAL`, it increased.

If you want to insert into a table with sequence, you may find you will fail with error `unique constraint violated`. However, when you tried on the second time, it would be a success, that's because sequence need check at the first time you use it.
Here one of the possible solutions:

**before insert, do the select query:**

```
select (you sequence name) from table.
```

**then,**

```
insert into table value(...).
```

It will work.